# Visual Studio 2010 Create Template Category

Tags: visual-studio-2010, templates

In visual studio I have created several templates for various languages to help make things easier for my team, but the problem I am having is how to create a custom category for the templates. I've tried adding folders to the ProjectTemplates folder and I am able to get a subcategory to generate under other categories (For example one template was located in "Visual C# -> Custom -> Custom Windows Forms Application") But ideally I would like to create a category that just says something like "Customer" or "Programming Team Name". Any ideas on how to do this properly?